# Ideals in the ring of gaussian integers of a given norm

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> What are the ideals in the ring of gaussian integers of a given norm, (say $20$) ?

The ring of integers is $\mathbb Z[i]$ and it is a PID, so any ideal must be principal.

If the ideal $I$ is factorized into prime ideals,

$I=\prod\limits_{\mathfrak{v}(p)\neq0}\mathfrak p^{\mathfrak{v}(p)}$

then the norm is defined as

$N(I)=\prod\limits_{\mathfrak{v}(p)\neq0}|\mathbb Z[i]/\mathfrak p|^{\mathfrak{v}(p)}$

If I consider the principal ideals $\langle n\rangle$ generated by some number $n$ then $\big|\mathbb Z[i]/\langle n\rangle\big|=n^2$ since then map $\phi:\mathbb Z_n[x]\to \mathbb Z[i]/\langle n\rangle$ defined by $\phi\left(f(x)\right)=f(i)+\langle n\rangle$ has kernel $\langle x^2+1\rangle$ which means that $\mathbb Z[i]/\langle n\rangle\simeq \mathbb Z_n[x]\big/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is $2$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb Z_n$

Does the above hold only for $n=$ prime ?

Can I deduce then there's no such ideal with norm $20$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principal ideal generated by the rational integer $n$ has norm $n^2$, so you won't find such an ideal of norm $20$. But there are other ideals around. The ideal generated by $2+i$, for example, has norm $5$, and from that, you should be able to construct an ideal of norm $20$. There's also the ideal generated by $2-i$.

Comment: but, Is $(2+i,2)$ principal in $\mathbb Z[i]$ ?

Comment: It's a principal ideal domain --- every ideal is principal.

Comment: Is it always true that $N\left((a)\right)=N_{\mathbb Q(i)/\mathbb Q}(a)$ for $a\in \mathbb Z[i]$ ?

Comment: Yes. It's true for primes, and both norms are multiplicative.

Comment: In a principal ideal domain, an ideal can look like it's not principal but then it turns out to be principal after all. Consider for example $\langle 10, 20 \rangle$ in good ol' $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @RobertSoupe Yes in your example it is $\langle 10\rangle$ but how can I write $\langle2+i,2\rangle$ with just one element ?

Comment: Any ideal that contains both $2+i$ and $2$ contains their difference, $i$. But $i$ is a unit, so the ideal is the entire set of Gaussian integers. In particular, it's not the ideal you are looking for. You want the ideal generated by the product, $2(2+i)$. Norms are multiplicative.

Comment: Any further questions, derivative? or are we OK now?